# java: ensure that there is only one instance of the type

Tags: java, oop, composite

I am following the example from:
https://www.baeldung.com/java-composite-pattern

```
public class FinancialDepartment implements Department {

    private Integer id;
    private String name;

    public void printDepartmentName() {
        System.out.println(getClass().getSimpleName());
    }

    // standard constructor, getters, setters
}
public class SalesDepartment implements Department {

    private Integer id;
    private String name;

    public void printDepartmentName() {
        System.out.println(getClass().getSimpleName());
    }

    // standard constructor, getters, setters
}

public class HeadDepartment implements Department {
    private Integer id;
    private String name;

    private List<Department> childDepartments;

    public HeadDepartment(Integer id, String name) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.childDepartments = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public void printDepartmentName() {
        childDepartments.forEach(Department::printDepartmentName);
    }

    public void addDepartment(Department department) {
        childDepartments.add(department);
    }

    public void removeDepartment(Department department) {
        childDepartments.remove(department);
    }
}
```

I want to prevent my self from able to add two of the same types to HeadDepartment

for example if it call add `addDepartment` twice for the same type, there should be only one

```
public class CompositeDemo {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Department salesDepartment = new SalesDepartment(
          1, "Sales department");

        Department salesDepartment2 = new SalesDepartment(
          1, "Sales department");
        Department salesDepartment3 = new SalesDepartment(
          3, "Sales department");


        Department financialDepartment = new FinancialDepartment(
          2, "Financial department");

        HeadDepartment headDepartment = new HeadDepartment(
          3, "Head department");

        headDepartment.addDepartment(salesDepartment);
        headDepartment.addDepartment(financialDepartment);

        // only keep the latest of same instanceof ie replace
        headDepartment.addDepartment(salesDepartment2);
        headDepartment.addDepartment(salesDepartment3);

        // this should only print twice one for salesDepartment3 and financialDepartment
        headDepartment.printDepartmentName();

    }
}
```

i suppose do i just iterate the list and if instanceof, replace and put?

```
public void addDepartment(Department department) {
        childDepartments.add(department);
    }
```

i would like to keep the order as well if the instnaceof Department was the first, i would like it to keep it as 1st, meaning it should print salesDepartment3 before financialDepartment

Comment: What happens if `addDepartment` is called once with `SalesDepartment` and then again with `Something extends SalesDepartment`? You want to replace the former with the latter or want to keep them both?

Comment: Use a `Set`? (e.g. `LinkedHashSet`).

Comment: @khachik say that's not a valid case at this moment that nothing will extend Department beyond its implementation. but if it would be easier then Something extend SalesDepartement is still SalesDepartment so replace it

Comment: if it is not the case then you can maintain a map of `Class -> instance` and add departments by their class. If you want to support hierarchy then you need to get the top parent class that is below `Department` in the hierarchy and use it as a key.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch but a Set wouldnt be able to discern between the same instanceof but with different constructor parameters. it will keep all of salesDepartment2 because of different id

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your addDepartment() needs to iterate over the list of children and compare each one's class to the class of the object you are adding.
Pseudo code:

```
Class addClass = itemToAdd.getClass();
for each child
{
    if (child.getClass() == addClass)
    {
        //class is already in the list so replace it.
    }
```